# How to delete in array by index?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im playing with nodejs and socket.io and i want to store users socket id and name.
i made a constructor

```
function user(socketid,name){
this.socketid = socketid;
this.name = name;
this.getName = function(){
    return this.name;
};
this.getId = function(){
    return this.socketid;
};
}
```

and i am inserting them into an array like this

```
users[socket.id] = new user(socket.id,'jirka');
```

which results in users being like this

```
[ '/chat#nksuCQdzHgBwO7x8AAAA': user {
socketid: '/chat#nksuCQdzHgBwO7x8AAAA',
name: 'jirka',
getName: [Function],
getId: [Function] },
'/chat#nmORiKZ9xzklDuUCAAAB': user {
socketid: '/chat#nmORiKZ9xzklDuUCAAAB',
name: 'jirka',
getName: [Function],
getId: [Function] } ]
```

now on disconnect event i want to delete them from an array by they socket.id

```
users.splice(socket.id,1);
```

but it doesnt work. When i did this without named indexes in array and the looping through them and if it matched socket id then i would delete them with iterator

```
users.splice(i,1);
```

and this worked. Can you help me figure out how to delete from array with named indexes?

Comment: Do you declare _users_ as an actual array? If your key _socket.id_ is a string, it doesn't add a new element in the array, but add it as an attribute of the array object, so all Array method don't works.

Comment: var users = new Array(); is at start of my code

Comment: Arrays are specific objects which have properties( indexes, in this context ) as numbers not strings. And the methods splice operate honoring that.
So, a better way for you to do this would be to use Maps.

Comment: I’d recommend using an array-like object instead of an array in this case. Arrays are sorted collections with access by _index_ (which is a natural number), whereas objects are optimized for random access by _key_ (which is a string, like in your case).

Comment: Don't use an array. Use a `Map`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer involves resolution of the problem, but not what you asked in specific. This is one of the best place, a 'Map' data-type is suitable to use. Hence, I will place a small example to show the operation -

```
let socketStore = new Map();
//when you have something to store - a socketId and data
socketStore.set(socketId, data)
// when you want to delete the socketId
socketStore.delete(socketId)
```

A very nice reference to Map - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Answer (score 0):

`delete users[socket.id]` worked despite using this without named indexes didnt worked and leaved the array with undefined index
weird

Comment: delete worked because inherently it is deleting a property of an object. But the use-case here doesn't support the array context.

Comment: Please read my answer. There is no such thing as named indexes. You have to forget this concept which is wrong.

Comment: Arrays are designed to work with "numbered" indexes not 'strings' indexes like you are trying to do. Not that you can't do, but array and its methods operate in a manner considering the array's values are stored in numbered indexes. 

So, if you are trying to store them in such a fashion do it in a simple object, not in arrays. 

I am not sure, if you even understand this. And I don't have to forget this concept @sjahan.

Comment: @HS the message was meant for OP. I totally agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

In your case u have an array of objects so u have to do it like this :

```
users = users.filter( user => users.getId() !=  current_socket_id );
```

Answer (score 0):

Beware of what you are doing.

An array is also a normal object. There is the array part where you can set items stored by indices and use array functions on them, like `slice`, and there is the classic object part where you can add properties to it.

**There is no such thing like named indices in an array.**

Doing `users[socket.id] = new user(socket.id,'jirka');`, you add a new property to the object, not in the array part. Therefore, it has nothing to do with `slice`.

To delete a property, just use the following: `delete users[socket.id];`